# Working outside of request context Error while trying to submit a form, using BottlePy

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, bottle

I'm learning Python and trying to send an email with Python from a simple HTML form. The main problem is submitting the form, because smtp mail settings are 100% alright.

Here is my Python code:

```
@post("/sendemail")
def sendemail():
    name = request.forms.get('name')
    subject = request.forms.get('Subject')
    email = request.forms.get('_replyto')
    message = request.forms.get('message')

    your_email = "testmail@gmail.com"
    your_password = "pass"

    # Logging in to our email account
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(your_email, your_password)

    # Sender's and Receiver's email address
    sender_email = "testmail@gmail.com"
    receiver_email = "testmail@gmail.com"

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(
        "First Name : " + str(name) + "\nEmail : " + str(email) +
        "\nSubject : " + str(subject) + "\nMessage : " + str(message))
    msg['Subject'] = 'New Response'
    msg['From'] = sender_email
    msg['To'] = receiver_email
    # Send the message via our own SMTP server.
    try:
        # sending an email
        server.send_message(msg)
    except EmailMessage.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return redirect('/', code=None)
```

```html
<form action="/sendemail" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="required"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="Subject" placeholder="Subject" required="required"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="email" name="_replyto" placeholder="E-mail" required="required"/><br/><br/>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message" required="required"></textarea><br/><br/>
<br/><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

The following Error is raised when I submit the email form. I am using BottlePy.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2022 12:57:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18483
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 868, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 1748, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "E:\Python\Day_82_Assignment_2_&_3\Engine\src\server.py", line 114, in sendemail
    name = request.forms.get('name')
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 432, in __get__
    obj = instance._get_current_object()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 554, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 33, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2022 12:57:49] "POST /sendemail HTTP/1.1" 500 750
```

I am sorry if the question is newbie. Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quite sure the issue was something different and that your new code especially your assumption about the change of the `return redirect('/', code=None)` line is not correct.

The exception traceback you initially get does say what it means:
"Working outside of request context". As you can see this exception is raised by flask. But as you stated you use bottle.

This leads me to the theory that you used the wrong import for `request`
Something like `from flask import request` instead of `from bottle import request`. In times of auto import functions of editors this accident may happen.

To be sure I tried to reproduce your issue. But without the mail stuff, which we can be very sure by reading the traceback is not causing your problem.

Therefor I have created this simple file structure:

```
.
├── app.py
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

Content of index.html

```html
<html>
<body>
    <form action="/sendemail" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="required"/><br/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="Subject" placeholder="Subject" required="required"/><br/><br/>
        <input type="email" name="_replyto" placeholder="E-mail" required="required"/><br/><br/>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message" required="required"></textarea><br/><br/>
    <br/><br/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Content of app.py to test this error does not occur on correct import

```py
from pathlib import Path

from bottle import route, redirect, run, post, template, request 

get_cwd = str(Path().absolute())
absolute_path = get_cwd.replace('templates', 'test_files')


@route("/")
def index():
    print(absolute_path)
    return template(absolute_path + "/templates/index.html")

@post("/sendemail")
def sendemail():
    name = request.forms.get('name')
    subject = request.forms.get('Subject')
    email = request.forms.get('_replyto')
    message = request.forms.get('message')

    your_email = "testmail@gmail.com"
    your_password = "pass"

    # Logging in to our email account
    # server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    # server.ehlo()
    # server.starttls()
    # server.login(your_email, your_password)

    # Sender's and Receiver's email address
    sender_email = "testmail@gmail.com"
    receiver_email = "testmail@gmail.com"

    # msg = EmailMessage()
    # msg.set_content(
    #     "First Name : " + str(name) + "\nEmail : " + str(email) +
    #     "\nSubject : " + str(subject) + "\nMessage : " + str(message))
    # msg['Subject'] = 'New Response'
    # msg['From'] = sender_email
    # msg['To'] = receiver_email
    # # Send the message via our own SMTP server.
    # try:
    #     # sending an email
    #     server.send_message(msg)
    # except EmailMessage.DoesNotExist:
    #     pass

    return redirect('/', code=None)


run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9090, debug=True)
```

`python app.py` starts the app as expected. Also the site is displayed as expected and on submit with correct form values I am redirected to the form again.

So I changed the app.py to import request from flask.

```py
from pathlib import Path

from bottle import route, redirect, run, post, template
from flask import request

get_cwd = str(Path().absolute())
absolute_path = get_cwd.replace('templates', 'test_files')


@route("/")
def index():
    print(absolute_path)
    return template(absolute_path + "/templates/index.html")

@post("/sendemail")
def sendemail():
    name = request.forms.get('name')
    subject = request.forms.get('Subject')
    email = request.forms.get('_replyto')
    message = request.forms.get('message')

    your_email = "testmail@gmail.com"
    your_password = "pass"

    # Logging in to our email account
    # server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    # server.ehlo()
    # server.starttls()
    # server.login(your_email, your_password)

    # Sender's and Receiver's email address
    sender_email = "testmail@gmail.com"
    receiver_email = "testmail@gmail.com"

    # msg = EmailMessage()
    # msg.set_content(
    #     "First Name : " + str(name) + "\nEmail : " + str(email) +
    #     "\nSubject : " + str(subject) + "\nMessage : " + str(message))
    # msg['Subject'] = 'New Response'
    # msg['From'] = sender_email
    # msg['To'] = receiver_email
    # # Send the message via our own SMTP server.
    # try:
    #     # sending an email
    #     server.send_message(msg)
    # except EmailMessage.DoesNotExist:
    #     pass

    return redirect('/', code=None)


run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9090, debug=True)
```

This time I get the expected traceback on form submit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lobi/stackoverflow/bottlepy_mail/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bottle.py", line 868, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/home/lobi/stackoverflow/bottlepy_mail/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1748, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "app.py", line 17, in sendemail
    name = request.forms.get('name')
  File "/home/lobi/stackoverflow/bottlepy_mail/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 432, in __get__
    obj = instance._get_current_object()
  File "/home/lobi/stackoverflow/bottlepy_mail/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 554, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()  # type: ignore
  File "/home/lobi/stackoverflow/bottlepy_mail/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 33, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

The only thing obviously different to the OP traceback is that it shows paths to the virtualenv I  have used for this.

So your initial approach was just fine.

Nevertheless I have on tip to for you how you can avoid to fall in such traps.
As you rely on many imports out of bottle I would just `import bottle`

The used names now are clrearly from bottle:

```py
from pathlib import Path

import bottle

get_cwd = str(Path().absolute())
absolute_path = get_cwd.replace('templates', 'test_files')


@bottle.route("/")
def index():
    print(absolute_path)
    return bottle.template(absolute_path + "/templates/index.html")

@bottle.post("/sendemail")
def sendemail():
    name = bottle.request.forms.get('name')
    subject = bottle.request.forms.get('Subject')
    email = bottle.request.forms.get('_replyto')
    message = bottle.request.forms.get('message')

    your_email = "testmail@gmail.com"
    your_password = "pass"

    # Logging in to our email account
    # server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    # server.ehlo()
    # server.starttls()
    # server.login(your_email, your_password)

    # Sender's and Receiver's email address
    sender_email = "testmail@gmail.com"
    receiver_email = "testmail@gmail.com"

    # msg = EmailMessage()
    # msg.set_content(
    #     "First Name : " + str(name) + "\nEmail : " + str(email) +
    #     "\nSubject : " + str(subject) + "\nMessage : " + str(message))
    # msg['Subject'] = 'New Response'
    # msg['From'] = sender_email
    # msg['To'] = receiver_email
    # # Send the message via our own SMTP server.
    # try:
    #     # sending an email
    #     server.send_message(msg)
    # except EmailMessage.DoesNotExist:
    #     pass

    return bottle.redirect('/', code=None)


bottle.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9090, debug=True)
```

Comment: well I've checked my older code and I paid attention to my imports and, voila - there were two imports for these requests: Flask and Bottle. Probably fighting each other, so your answer is quite helpful! Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've managed to find where my problem is. The key is in this line of code:

```
return redirect('/', code=None)
```

I have changed it to:

```
return template(absolute_path + "/templates/index.html")
```

So the working code, for sending emails with BottlePy is:

```
get_cwd = str(Path().absolute())
absolute_path = get_cwd.replace('templates', 'test_files')


@route("/")
def index():
    print(absolute_path)
    return template(absolute_path + "/templates/index.html")


@route("/sendemail", method='POST')
def form():
    name = request.forms.get("name")
    subject = request.forms.get("subject")
    reply_to = request.forms.get("reply_to")
    message = request.forms.get("message")

    send_from = "test@gmail.com"
    send_to = "test@gmail.com"

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(f"Hello, my name is: {name}\n {message}\n\n "
                    f"You can further contact me at this email address: {reply_to}")
    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg["From"] = send_from
    msg["To"] = send_to

    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login("test@gmail.com", "test")
    server.send_message(msg)

    server.quit()

    return template(absolute_path + "/templates/index.html")
    # return template("index.html")


run(host='127.0.0.1', port=9090, debug=True)
```

Bottle Py is mainly working with returning templates for cases like mine. And their documentation helped me a lot. Case closed!